# If $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable in $[-3,9]$ and $f'(x)$ ∈ $[-2,8]$ for all x ∈ $(-3,9)$.

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable in $[-3,9]$ and $f'(x)\in[-2,8]$ for all $x \in(-3,9)$. Find the greatest value of $f(9)-f(-3)$.

Comment: What did you try? MVT looks promising..

Answer (score 2):

Hint. By the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there is some $t\in(-3,9)$ such that
$$f(9)-f(-3)=f'(t)\cdot (9-(-3))\leq 8\cdot 12.$$
Is there any function which attains this greatest value?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=ax+b$.

Upon condition:
$$-2\le f'(x)\le 8 \Rightarrow -2\le a\le8.$$

Maximize:
$$f(9)-f(-3)=9a+b-(-3a+b)=12a\le 12\cdot 8=96.$$